# Listas en HTML5 y JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Quiero hacer una lista que al seleccionar uno de sus elementos aparezca en la misma página una imagen relacionada a dicho elemento, al seleccionar otro elemento aparezca la imagen del segundo elemento y así con los demás elementos, para que al final aparezcan las imágenes de los elementos seleccionados ya sea 1 o las veces que lo haya seleccionado, me salió con onclick, pero tengo que hacerla con una función en JS.

Éste es mi código:

```js
var forma = document.getElementById("forma"),
Ferrari = document.getElementById("Accion1"),
BMW = document.getElementById("Accion2"),
AUDI = document.getElementById("Accion3"),
Lamborghini = document.getElementById("Accion4"),
AlfaRomeo = document.getElementById("Accion5"),
Maserati = document.getElementById("Accion6"),
Tesla = document.getElementById("Accion7"),
forma.addEventListener("click", carros, false);

carros();

function carros() {

}
```

```html
<header>
 <h1>Examen 2</h1>
</header>

<form id="forma">

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Selecciona un carro.</legend>

    <ul>
        <li id="Accion1"><a href="#" >Ferrari</a></li>    
        <li id="Accion2"><a href="#" >BMW</a></li>    
        <li id="Accion3"><a href="#" >AUDI</a></li>    
        <li id="Accion4"><a href="#" >Lamborghini</a></li>    
        <li id="Accion5"><a href="#" >Alfa Romeo</a></li>    
        <li id="Accion6"><a href="#" >Maserati</a></li>   
        <li id="Accion7"><a href="#" >Tesla</a></li>   
    </ul>
    <hr />

  </fieldset>

</form>
<script  src="js/ctrlAutorizacion.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hola Joseph, bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Por favor, añade el código que tengas actualmente.

Comment: Gracias @GustavoGarcía

Comment: ¿En qué parte se relacionan los item con las imágenes?

Comment: Es lo que no se, anteriormente habia hecho uno parecido, era de una torteria y tenia que seleccionar diferentes tortas y se iba sumando el precio para dar el total, esa la hice asi: a cada checkbox le puse un id y un nombre, y cree unn arreglo en donde en el js iba agregando las seleccionadas y sumando en un contador, luego lo mande a llamar con output, pero con imagenes y lista no se como hacerl, como lo puse en el codigo si no agrego el href al darle click no hace absolutamente nada, me imagino podria hacer un condicional en el js que al darle click en Item1 en un output devuelva la imagen

Answer (score 1):

me gustaría ayudarte, primero debería orientarme en tu duda.

- Primero: asumo que las imágenes las tienes en una carpeta ubicada en el mismo directorio que el documento html.
- Segundo: de alguna manera debes relacionar la opción con cada imagen, ya sea por el texto del li (la imagen correspondiente al `li` con `id= action1` deberá llamarse `ferrari.jpg`) , o con algún atributo del elemento `li` (Ejemplo `id='action' data='Ferrari'`)
- Tercero: crea un `div` para agregar las imágenes correspondientes y asígnale un `id`
- Debes asociar un manejador de eventos a los elementos `li` de tu documento mediante `addeventlistener`, por ejemplo:

  ```
  document.getElementsByTagName("LI").addEventListener("click", function()
  {
       //aquí, en el cuerpo de la función agregaríamos las imágenes al div 
       // mencionado en el tercer item
  });
  ```
- Cuarto: creas un elemento `img` y le asignas la propiedad `src` con la imagen relacionada (aquí depende de cómo obtengas el nombre de la imagen, de qué atributo del `li` lo sacas, del atributo `data` o del texto del `li`)(aquí es donde tengo una duda, ya que uso jquery y no estoy seguro de que la sintaxis sea correcta, en el cuerpo de la función del punto anterior debes obtener del elemento donde se hizo click la propiedad que te interese, ejemplo:

  ```
  var nombreImagen=this.getAttribute("data")+".jpg";

  var elem = document.createElement("img");

  elem.setAttribute("src", nombreImagen);
  ```
- quinto: obtienes el elemento `div` mediante su `id` y agregas un nodo hijo creado antes  `document.getElementById("idDivPunto3").appendChild(elem);`

  Espero que te sirva para orientarte, todo el código lo hice en el aire.
  creo que es un camino para llegar a tu objetivo, de seguro harán correcciones que te servirán

Comment: Hola Daniel, te he editado la respuesta. Recuerda usar bacticks " ` " para formatear codigo y nombres de variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo terminé. Les dejo el código por si le sirve a alguien:

```js
function imagen(valor){
    if(valor === 'ferrari'){
        document.getElementById('carro').innerHTML = '<img src="img/ferrari.jpg" alt="Ferrari"/>';
    }
    else if(valor === 'mercedes'){
        document.getElementById('carro').innerHTML = '<img src="img/mercedes.jpg" alt="Mercedes"/>';
    }
    else if(valor === 'lamborghini'){
        document.getElementById('carro').innerHTML = '<img src="img/lambo.jpg" alt="Lamborghini"/>';
    }
    else if(valor === 'mclaren'){
        document.getElementById('carro').innerHTML = '<img src="img/mclaren.jpg" alt="McLaren"/>';
    }
    else if(valor === 'tesla'){
        document.getElementById('carro').innerHTML = '<img src="img/tesla.jpg.jpg" alt="Tesla"/>';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('carro').innerHTML = '<img src="" alt=""/>';
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Carros</h1>
</header>
<form>
    <fieldset style="text-align: center;">
    <legend>Selecciona un carro para verlo.</legend>
    <p>
        <label accesskey="C">
            Carros:<br>
            <select name="carros" required size="6" onchange="imagen(this.value)">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Seleccione</option>
                <option value="ferrari">Ferrari F40</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLR</option>
                <option value="lamborghini">Lamborghini Veneno</option>
                <option value="mclaren">McLaren P1</option>
                <option value="tesla">Tesla Hypercar</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </p>
    <br>
    <div id="carro">
  </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Según tu pregunta inicial, ésta no es una respuesta válida porque no cumple la condición "para que al final aparezcan las imágenes de los elementos seleccionados ya sea 1 o las veces que lo haya seleccionado". Si seleccionas un nuevo coche, según esta solución, el anterior desaparece. Si quieres que se vayan agregando las imágenes una solución rápida sería cambiar los `.innerHTML = ...` por `.innerHTML += ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Segun tu respuesta para que no hayan tantos if anidados quizas te convendria usar un switch

```
function imagen(valor){
   var val = valor;
   switch(val){
      case 'tesla':
      document.getElementById('carro').innerHTML = '<img src="img/mercedes.jpg" alt="Mercedes"/>';
      break;
      case 'mclaren':
      document.getElementById('carro').innerHTML = '<img src="img/mclaren.jpg" alt="McLaren"/>';
      break;
      default:
      document.getElementById('carro').innerHTML = '<img src="" alt=""/>';
      break;
   }
}
```